# Tkinter Frame resizes when I add button?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have the following code that creates a window with frame in it:

```
import tkinter as tk

class FrameClass:
    def __init__(self, root, hl_color, hl_thickness, height, width):
        self.root = root
        self.hl_color = hl_color
        self.hl_thickness = hl_thickness
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def make_frame(self):
        frame = tk.Frame(self.root, highlightbackground=self.hl_color, highlightthickness=self.hl_thickness, width=self.width, height=self.height)
        padx, pady = self.width/10, self.height/10
        frame.grid(pady=padx, padx=pady)
        return frame
    
class ButtonFunction:
    def __init__(self):
        print("click")

class ButtonClass:
    def __init__(self, root, text, bg, padx, pady, relief):
        self.root = root
        self.text = text
        self.bg = bg
        self.padx = padx
        self.pady = pady
        self.relief = relief
    
    def button_function(self):
        ButtonFunction()

    def make_button(self):
        button = tk.Button(self.root, text=self.text, bg=self.bg, padx=self.padx, pady=self.pady, relief=self.relief, command=self.button_function)
        button.grid()

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Application")
        self.root.geometry("400x300")
        self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def application(self):
        F = FrameClass(self.root, "BLACK", 5, 400*0.9, 300*0.9)
        frame = F.make_frame()
        # button_color, padx, pady, relief = "GREY", 25, 10, tk.GROOVE
        # B1 = ButtonClass(frame, "Button 1", button_color, padx, pady, relief)
        # B1.make_button()
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    M = Main()
    M.application()
```

It looks like I want, but if I add a button by uncommenting these lines:

```
# button_color, padx, pady, relief = "GREY", 25, 10, tk.GROOVE
# B1 = ButtonClass(frame, "Button 1", button_color, padx, pady, relief)
# B1.make_button()
```

Then the frame gets resized to the size of the button. What's going on here? I do not want it to resize when I add buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `frame.grid_propagate(False)` to `make_frame`, it should retain the size you set in `FrameClass.__init__()`

```
def make_frame(self):
    frame = tk.Frame(self.root, highlightbackground=self.hl_color, 
    highlightthickness=self.hl_thickness, width=self.width, height=self.height)
    # disable grid_propagate to keep the frame at the defined size
    frame.grid_propagate(False)
    padx, pady = self.width/10, self.height/10
    frame.grid(pady=padx, padx=pady)
    return frame
```

As an aside, you might want to look into how class inheritance works in Python. It's usually easier to have your widget classes inherit from the relevant base widget class than it is to have separate `make...` methods - just food for thought!

```
class FrameClass(tk.Frame):  # inherit from the built in Frame class
    def __init__(self, root, hl_color, hl_thickness, height, width) -> None:
        # use super() to initialize the superclass (tk.Frame) with the given args
        super().__init__(
            root, 
            highlightbackground=hl_color, 
            highlightthickness=hl_thickness, 
            height=height, 
            width=width,
        )
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        # use 'self' here to refer to this widget, i.e. the frame!
        self.grid_propagate(False)
        padx, pady = self.width / 10, self.height / 10
        self.grid(pady=padx, padx=pady)
```

Naturally, you can do the same thing with your `ButtonClass` or any other class